Is this functional jointly continuous on the product space?
Let $\Omega : = [0,1]^2$ be our sample space and $\Delta \Omega$ the set of probability measures on $\Omega$. Let $\omega \in \Omega$ denote the typical element of $\Omega$.
Let $x := (x_1,x_2) \in X :=\{x\in \Omega: x_1 \leq x_2\}$. Define $\mathcal{V}: X \times \Delta \Omega  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:
\begin{align*}    
\mathcal{V}(x,\mu):=\int\limits_{\substack{\omega\in \Omega,\\ \omega_1 \geq x_2}}d\mu+\int\limits_{\substack{\omega\in \Omega,\\ \omega_1\in [x_1,x_2],\\\omega_1>\omega_2}}d\mu+0.5\int\limits_{\substack{\omega\in \Omega,\\ \omega_1\in [x_1,x_2],\\\omega_1=\omega_2}}d\mu
\end{align*}
My question is, is $\mathcal{V}$ continuous on the product space $X \times \Delta \Omega$? I'm very much a beginner in functional analysis. I know that linear functionals are continuous if and only if they are bounded. But $\mathcal{V}$ is not linear in $x$, though it's linear in $\mu$. Hence I'm confused how to proceed. Any help is most appreciated.

What is the topology on $\Delta\Omega$?

That of weak convergence, which can be metrized via the Prokhorov metric.

It is not even continuous for fixed $x$. You can find a counterexample from a sequence of Dirac measures.
